# The difference between 245/70r16. Instead of a 265/70r16

Tags: chevrolet, tires, avalanche

I have a 2004 Chevrolet Avalanche with the tow package ,would it be alright to use 245/70r16 tire instead of  265/70r16?

Answer (score 1):

If you think your Avalanche is getting okay mileage now (most likely between 15-18 highway), you're going to hurt it worse by using those tires. The ones you want to use are shorter overall. Secondly, since they are skinnier tires, by two centimeters, you won't have as much grip and possibly stability as you do now. The speedometer will be off by a bit, reading faster than you're actually going.

You can use them, but there's some large tradeoffs for doing so. Personally, it's not something I'd do.

Comment: @teresa this is a useful link, showing revolutions per mile ie how it will affect the fuel consumption : https://www.tacomaworld.com/tirecalc?tires=245-75r16-265-75r16

Comment: Another consideration if the vehicle is used for towing is the load rating of the new tires. A tire with a lower load rating may have difficulties towing, up to and including tire failure. If you don't tow, or tow exclusively light loads, it won't matter.